# Swipe support with bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**SOLVED** Reference https://github.com/avinoamr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe

Hey guys i'm trying to design a website for my small business.. My primary goal is to add swipe support to my bootstrap custom carousel. I have found several answers to this but I cant seem to get it to work on my carousel. After a hour of trial and error I seek some advice...

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your help!

**update** Im still trying to get this to work. Ive tried using the jquery cdn instead of local file.. Ive always tried using the hammer.js method. I got to thinking maybe the div overlay was stopping it, so I removed those for testing purpose without success.. I also tried removing data interval with no success.... Again any help would be appreciated thank you.

/* My Carousel HTML */

```
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000" id="bs-carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="slide-1" role="img" aria-label="Shingle Roofing Free Estimates Licensed Bonded Insured"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <header>
            <h1>Shingle Roofing</h1>        
            <h3>"Get the Estimate You Deserve!"</h3>
        </header>
        <a href="tel:+12178207597" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Call Now (217) 820-7597</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="slide-2" role="img" aria-label="Metal Roofing Free Estimates Licensed Bonded Insured"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <header>
            <h1>Metal Roofing</h1>        
            <h3>"Get the Estimate You Deserve!"</h3>
         </header>      
        <a href="tel:+12178207597" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Call Now (217) 820-7597</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="slide-3" role="img" aria-label="Rubber Roofing Free Estimates Licensed Bonded Insured"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <header>
            <h1>Rubber Roofing</h1>        
            <h3>"Get the Estimate You Deserve!"</h3>
        </header>
        <a href="tel:+12178207597" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Call Now (217) 820-7597</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

/* Slide Support Script */

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
         $("#bs-carousel").swiperight(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('next');  
                });  
           $("#bs-carousel").swipeleft(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('prev');  
       });  
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this one yet but looks like it would work

http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Mobile-friendly-Carousel-Slideshow-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

DEMO: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-friendly-Carousel-Slideshow-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap/